# Error in R when running whole chunk of r code but not if lines are run seperately before

Tags: r

I run the lines of the following code seperately before running the whole block they run without an error however when I don't do that they produce an error: "Error in rr[i] <- summary(sim(fit1, x = bf0, x1 = bf1))$qi.stats$rr[1]: replacement has length 0" same for when I try to run the whole script e.g. before knitting my rmd file to pdf

```
fit1bm <- zelig(lula ~   bf + sexo + escola + renda2 + idade + region + 
                hdi.2000 + metropolitan + growth, 
                weights=matched.data$weights,model="logit",data=matched.data)
inc <- levels(matched.data$renda2) #need to refactor because one factor was dropped after rescaling (high income)
reg <- levels(matched.data$region)[2]
rr <- rr.p <-  pred.bf0 <- pred.bf1 <- sig <- vector(length=length(levels(matched.data$renda2)))
fd <- matrix(NA,ncol=4,nrow=length(rr))
for(i in 1:length(inc)){
    bf0 <- setx(fit1bm , bf=0, renda2=inc[i], region=reg)
    bf1 <- setx(fit1bm ,bf=1, renda2=inc[i], region=reg)
    out <- sim(fit1bm,x=bf0,x1=bf1)
    rr[i] <-summary(out)$qi.stats$rr[1]
    sig[i] <- summary(out)$qi.stats$rr[3]>1
    post.rr <- out$qi$rr
    rr.p[i] <- 2* (1-sum(post.rr>1)/1000) #two sided p-value
    pred.bf0[i] <-  mean(sim(fit1bm,x=bf0)$qi$ev)
    pred.bf1[i] <-  mean(sim(fit1bm,x=bf1)$qi$ev)
    fd[i,] <-  summary(out)$qi.stats$fd
    }
colnames(fd) <- colnames(summary(out)$qi.stats$fd)
ef <- cbind(pred.bf0,pred.bf1,rr,rr.p,sig)
rownames(ef) <- rownames(fd) <- inc
cat("Results for",reg,"controling for\n");print(fit1bm$call)
the.table <- cbind(table(tmp$renda2,tmp$bf),table(matched.data$renda2,matched.data$bf))[,c(3,1,4,2)]
the.table <- cbind(the.table,ef)
print(xtable(the.table,digits=c(0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,0)))
```

I printed results between the steps and looked at the length of vectors but none were zero

I printed the results between the steps of the loop and compared the length of the included vectors none shower null

Comment: Two suggestions: try and use a breakpoint. This will tell you the progress of the entire script. https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-the-RStudio-IDE . I'd also say that the for loop is seldom necessary in R. There are better alternatives such as the `map_` function. In your case, you would probably need the multi-argument version which is map2_

Comment: Setting a breakpoint (insert a call to `browser()` just before the bad line, or get RStudio to set one) is a good idea.  Don't try switching to `map*` functions; that will just be a distraction.  (Think about switching once you find the current issue.)  You can use `options(error = recover)` which will cause R to drop into the debugger when the error occurs, and you can examine variables to see what has gone wrong.

Comment: Don't use `1:length(inc)`, always use `seq_along(inc)`.

Comment: @user2554330 that's nice advice but does not change what the produced vector is.

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code you posted:  `stats$rr[3]`  vs.  `stats$rr[1]`   Which is correct?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  How do you know it doesn't change the vector?  We don't have the dataset, so it could be that `inc` is length zero.  In that case, `1:length(inc)` is not the same as `seq_along(inc)`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: regarding `rr[3]` vs `rr[1]`, I think you overlooked the previous line.

Comment: @user2554330  oh, yep, the same func called twice in a row.